# How can I add a camera to my scene such as my required mesh object will always be in it's view irrespective of its size?

Tags: python, camera

I am trying to find a way to add a camera such as when I add it to my blender scene it will set it's `location`, `rotation_euler` and `lens(focal_length)` properties such as my required mesh object will always be in camera's view.

Here what I have done till now

```
import bpy
import math

def turnaround():

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    camera_data = bpy.data.cameras.new(name="turnaround_camera")
    camera_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="turnaround_camera", object_data=camera_data)
    scene.collection.objects.link(camera_object)

    turnaround_camera = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("turnaround_camera")
    
    target_obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("Hi")

    target_obj_dimensions = list(target_obj.dimensions)

    max_val = max(target_obj_dimensions)
    fl_factor = 50 * 2 / 30

    camera_height = target_obj_dimensions[2]
    camera_loc = fl_factor * max_val

    turnaround_camera.location.z = camera_height/2
    turnaround_camera.location.y = -1*(camera_loc)

    rotation_x = math.radians(88.1723)
    rotation_y = 0 
    rotation_z = 0  

    turnaround_camera.rotation_euler = (rotation_x, rotation_y, rotation_z)


turnaround()
```

In the script I am adding a new camera and setting it's properties such as my object will be in it's view, but the thing is as I have hardcoded few things like `rotation` values
`fl_factor` due to which object of default size kind of coming fine, but as soon as I change their dimension it is failing.

You can refer to this image for better understanding of my requirements.

[image]

Any help would be great.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well seems like it is really simple we can just use the following snippet and it will do the rest

```
turnaround_camera.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
turnaround_camera.constraints["Track To"].target = target_obj
```

I am still not sure if this the best way to go for or not but it works.